# How would pass values to my database? (React JS, MongoDB, MERN method)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm writing program that uses React as front-end, and an Express/Node API for the backend. I do not know how to submit the ShippingInfo to my mongo database.

here is my frontend code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
```

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createOrder, clearErrors  } from '../../actions/orderActions'
import MetaData from '../layout/MetaData'
import CheckoutSteps from './CheckoutSteps'

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import { Button,Modal    } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ProtectedRoute from '../route/ProtectedRoute'

const ConfirmOrder = ({ history }) => {

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const handleShow = () => setShow(true);



const { cartItems, shippingInfo } = useSelector(state => state.cart)
const { user } = useSelector(state => state.auth)

// Calculate Order Prices
const itemsPrice = cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.quantity, 0)
const shippingPrice = itemsPrice > 200 ? 0 : 25
//const taxPrice = Number((0.05 * itemsPrice).toFixed(2))
const totalPrice = (itemsPrice + shippingPrice ).toFixed(2)
const order = {
    orderItems: cartItems,
    shippingInfo
}
const processToPayment = () => {
    const data = {
        itemsPrice: itemsPrice.toFixed(2),
        shippingPrice,
        //taxPrice,
        totalPrice

    }


    sessionStorage.setItem('orderInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
    dispatch(createOrder(order))
    history.push('/payment')

}


return (
    <Fragment>

        <MetaData title={'Confirm Order'} />

        <CheckoutSteps shipping confirmOrder />

        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-8 mt-5 order-confirm">

                <h4 className="mb-3">Shipping Info</h4>
                <p><b>Name:</b> {shippingInfo.name}</p>
                <p><b>Phone:</b> {shippingInfo.phoneNo}</p>
                <p><b>City:</b> {shippingInfo.city}</p>
                <p><b>Email:</b> {shippingInfo.email}</p>
                <p><b>Region:</b> NCR </p>
                <p className="mb-4"><b>Address:</b> {`${shippingInfo.address},${shippingInfo.barangay}, ${shippingInfo.city},  ${shippingInfo.postalCode}`}</p>

                <hr />
                <h4 className="mt-4">Your Cart Items:</h4>

                {cartItems.map(item => (
                    <Fragment>
                        <hr />
                        <div className="cart-item my-1" key={item.product}>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-4 col-lg-2">
                                    <img src={item.image} alt="Laptop" height="45" width="65" />
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-5 col-lg-6">
                                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                                </div>


                                <div className="col-4 col-lg-4 mt-4 mt-lg-0">
                                    <p>{item.quantity} x ${item.price} = <b>${(item.quantity * item.price).toFixed(2)}</b></p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                    </Fragment>
                ))}



            </div>

            <div className="col-12 col-lg-3 my-4">
                <div id="order_summary">
                    <h4>Order Summary</h4>
                    <hr />
                    <p>Subtotal:  <span className="order-summary-values">${itemsPrice}</span></p>
                    <p>Shipping: <span className="order-summary-values">${shippingPrice}</span></p>


                    <hr />

                    <p>Total: <span className="order-summary-values">${totalPrice}</span></p>

                    <hr />
                    <button id="checkout_btn" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={handleShow}>Proceed to Payment</button>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>




        <Modal
    show={show}
    onHide={handleClose}
    backdrop="static"
    keyboard={false}
>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Confirmation Of Order</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body classname = "text-center">
    This is message is to confirm your order. Once you click the understood button your order will be processed. <br/>
    *this message will not close unless you click on Cancel or Understood*
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer >
    <Button variant="secondary"  onClick={handleClose}>
        Cancel
    </Button>
    <Button variant="primary" onClick={processToPayment}>Understood</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
    </Fragment>
)
```

}

export default ConfirmOrder

and here is my backend code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({

```
shippingInfo: {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phoneNo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postalCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    barangay: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    province: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    notes: {
        type: String
    }
},
/*
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
},*/
orderItems: [{
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Product'
    },
}],


itemsPrice: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    defaultValue: 0.0
},
shippingPrice: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    defaultValue: 0.0
},
totalPrice: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    defaultValue: 0.0
},
orderStatus: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: 'Processing'
},
deliveredAt: {
    type: Date
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
},
```

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)

Comment: [MERN getting started](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-mern-stack) you can check this post.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mre] and [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You should give us a *minimal* example to reproduce the issue you want to solve.